# How can I get shipping address of invoice?

Tags: square-connect, square

I have scoured the square developer documentation and I couldn't find how to retrieve the shipping address from a paid invoice.

The ONLY documentation I've been able to find that utilized the shipping address is here:

https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/objects/Payment

However, when I query to get a payment, there is no shipping_address object in the returned json.

How do I get the shipping address?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to request nor retrieve the shipping address via the Invoices API at this time. This feature is currently only available in the Invoices section within the Square Seller Dashboard or Square Point of Sale application.